# How to add a cookie or localstorage using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently working in a new project using React Hooks and im quite lost. I checked some libraries from other developers to add a cookie using hooks but I'm not comfortable using external dependencies. Can someone tell me about how to include cookies or local storage on Hooks ?

Comment: You probably don't need hooks to work with cookie/localStorage, or show your code, where you want to replace regular cookie/storage use with hooks

Comment: I had to use hooks  I just need to add a cookieBar

Comment: You are free to use hooks for whatever you need but what does this have to do with cookies and ls? And what's cookiebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading or writing cookie values are actions which are not directly related to anything React, so you would want to look into a general read/write cookies library/snippet using javascript.

When you interact with that library or snippet you probably want to read cookie values inside the `useEffect` hook (since reading cookies are impure), and write cookies inside a click handler on your cookie bar accept button.